# Jacob.jar cannot find jacob-1.18-x86.dll

Tags: java, autohotkey, jacob

I am trying to write Java code that uses autohotkey, specifically the autoitx4java implementation. I have the imports

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import autoitx4java.AutoItX;
```

As well as have added Jacob.jar, AutoItX4Java.jar and sqljdbc4.jar in the build path (sql jdbc is for other parts of the code). It doesn't compile because of an unsatisfied link error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jacob-1.18-x86 in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at com.jacob.com.LibraryLoader.loadJacobLibrary(LibraryLoader.java:184)
    at com.jacob.com.JacobObject.<clinit>(JacobObject.java:110)
    at autoitx4java.AutoItX.<init>(AutoItX.java:181)
    at MainTest.login(MainTest.java:126)
    at MainTest.setadmin(MainTest.java:181)
    at MainTest.runbasic(MainTest.java:21)
    at MainTest.main(MainTest.java:15)
```

I have the `jacob-1.18-x86.dll` in the system32 folder (windows 8.1 is the OS) as well as `jacob-1.18-x64.dll` and `jacob-1.18-M3-x64.dll`, just in case it wanted to use the 64 bit dll. I tried adding `C:/Windows/System32` to the `jacob.jar` "Native library location" (using eclipse) from some website, but that didn't work. Some other site suggested putting the dll in the `C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin` folder, so I did that, but it still throws the error. This code used to work on a different machine, but now it won't compile because of the unsatisfied link. I can't figure out where to put the jacob-1.18-x86 to get it to find it.

Comment: If the OS is 64 bit then the `x86` dll, which is 32bit, should be in `c:\windows\syswow64`

Comment: Ok, that worked also. Will have to keep this info for later. Thanks so much!

Comment: Got a "Can't get object clsid from progid" when doing that, but I'll open a new question (have to wait 90 minutes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, copied it into the "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_65\bin" folder and it worked. Apparently it only looks there for the jacob dll's.

Comment: This solution works probably because JAVA_HOME (JRE bin folder) is set in the environment variables. So to generalize the solutions we need to have the path to DLL in the environment PATH variable.

Answer (score 0):

Copied `jacob-1.19-x64.dll` file under application using jre8 folder like, `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_65\bin"` and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\bin
it's work

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).