# How do I resolve the "no jacob-1.xx-x86" Unsatisfiable Link Error in Apache Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, jacob

Tomcat keeps throwing an `Unsatisfiable Link Error` for Jacob, despite the fact that I have copied the Jacob jar into the `libs` directory for Tomcat. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for this comes from [this troubleshooting article](https://support.pitneybowes.com/VFP06_KnowledgeWithSidebarTroubleshoot?id=kA280000000PEJBCA4&popup=false&lang=en_US) and [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33919919/jacob-jar-cannot-find-jacob-1-18-x86-dll?rq=1):

1. Navigate to the [SourceForge project's files](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jacob-project/files/jacob-project/). Find the version of Jacob you're using. Download the zip file.
2. Once downloaded, extract the `*-x86.dll` and `*-x64.dll` files into the `bin` directory for Tomcat.
3. Restart Tomcat
4. Navigate to the webapp/page that is throwing the error. It should now be resolved.